# Limited access to shared folder

Tags: java, security

I created shared folder in server PC,

and I want to access that folder only & only from my java application.

How can I do it? Any advices?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an operating system question, nothing do to with Java specifically; the only way to achieve this effect is to allow access to the folder only to a specific user and then run Java with that same user. Again, there is nothing that you can do about this in Java.

Comment: What do you think about giving certificate to my application and give permission to applications with that certificate

Comment: Certificates have nothing to do with accessing folders.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible JUST with java, you need something on top. Most probably the OS will be your number one option. Have a user on the OS that is the only one who can access the folder, then develop a Java app that will run only from that user.

Just an idea.